# How to store the print statement output in the new variable name using perl?

Tags: perl

Is it possible to store the print statement into variable name using `perl`?

Here is my print statement,

```
print "$fixed\n";
```

I want to store the this print statement output in new variable. Is it possible to do?

Comment: It is already stored in `$fixed`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Or do you want to store `print "$fixed\n";` this in a variable? why?

Comment: Yeah it is already stored now i had used print statement along with \n.Is it possible to store the variable print statement \n output into new variable .@AruneshSingh

Comment: After using \n the output of $variable will differs .I need to store output into new variable after \n is given .@AbhiNickz

Comment: Am trying to use the variable with \n output .So am trying to sabe those print statement into new variable name.Then i will use the new variable name for further process. @AbhiNickz

Comment: `my $new = "$fixed\n"; print $new;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign to a variable instead of print it:

```
my $var = "$fixed\n";
```

For more complex scenarios, use [sprintf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html), example:

```
my $var = sprintf("%02d - %s - %f", 1, $fixed, 3.1415);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer you have already seen an accepted does things in a slightly different order than you asked for. You asked:

> How to store the print statement output in the new variable name using perl?

The answer you have stores some data in a variable and then prints the contents of the variable. That has the same effect, but it's not, strictly speaking, what you asked for.

But it's possible to do anything in Perl. Including configuring a scalar variable to store any data that is printed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $output;

# Call open(), giving it a reference to a scalar, instead of
# a filename.
open my $fh, '>', \$output or die $!;

# Now anything printed to that filehandle, is appended to
# your scalar variable.
print $fh "this is\na test\n";

# ... which you can print to STDOUT
print $output;
```

It's possible to take this a step further, by using `select()` to make your scalar filehandle, the default output filehandle.

```
select $fh;

print "Something";
```